# How the annotation @ApplicationPath from JAX-RS works side to side with a non-rest resource?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

I've been creating a restful api and I had some issues that I couldn't find anything about it over the internet.

What happens if I have a restful api with an `applicationPath` pointing to `"/"` and some non-rest resource on the same project? The same question is valid to static content that I've added to a project and it got ignored.

Let's use a domain `foo.com` and the context name `bar` as example:

---

I've created a rest interface with an `@applicationPath` pointing to `"/"` and a resource with a `@path` pointing to `publications`.

So I'd have `foo.com/bar/publications` as part of the restful api, and it would be functional.

But if I have a static content like `api-doc`, which should appear on `foo.com/bar/api-doc` it's just ignored.

The same happens with a non-rest api, like a simple java's servlet.. Everything after the slash that's not a rest resource is ignored.

---

Is there a way of making them work together using this `applicationPath` pointing to `"/"` or is it impossible? Because I can't find anything about it on the documentation. I just want to understand how it works to make a better use of it.

Comment: instead of `@applicationPath` as `"/"` to `"/rest"`

Comment: I know I could use something like `"/rest"`, but I just want to know why this situation happens and if there is a way to use rest and non-rest using the same `basePath`

Comment: Instead of using annotation based configuration use `web.xml`, try once I didn't checked. :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be of relevance to others running into these kinds of issues.

It sounds like you have a situation of URL path shadowing. Consider the order in which you declare your mappings.

From [Servlet 3 spec, section 12.1](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/servlet-3.0-fr-eval-oth-JSpec/servlet-3_0-final-spec.pdf?AuthParam=1509608907_3cd46593e315f7b03f9a257f09aa2920):

> The first successful match is used with no further matches attempted:
>
> 1. The container will try to find an exact match of the path of the request to the path of the servlet. A successful match selects the
>      servlet.
> 2. The container will recursively try to match the longest path-prefix. This is done by stepping down the path tree a directory
>      at a time, using the ’/’ character as a path separator. The longest
>      match determines the servlet selected.
> 3. If the last segment in the URL path contains an extension (e.g. .jsp), the servlet container will try to match a servlet that handles
>      requests for the extension. An extension is defined as the part of the
>      last segment after the last ’.’ character.
> 4. Versions of this specification prior to 2.5 made use of these mapping techniques as a suggestion rather than a requirement, allowing
>      servlet containers to each have their different schemes for mapping
>      client requests to servlets.  116 Java Servlet Specification •
>      November 2009
> 5. If neither of the previous three rules result in a servlet match, the container will attempt to serve content appropriate for the
>      resource requested. If a "default" servlet is defined for the
>      application, it will be used. Many containers provide an implicit
>      default servlet for serving content.

Alternatively, you might be inadvertently [overriding](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/ApplicationPath.html) your @ApplicationPath with a servlet-mapping element in your web.xml

Hope some will find this useful.